# custom View for universal application

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I believe, that this question is duplicated, but i can't find it =(.
How to create own UIView class, which is loaded from (iPhone/iPad)*.xib

I was trying next things:

```
@interface CurtainView : UIView
```

...

```
- (id)init {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
         self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurtainView_iphone" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    }
    else {                
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurtainView_ipad" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"there should be some animation on view appirance");

}
```

and ...

```
CurtainView* curtain = [[CurtainView alloc] init];
NSLog(@"before");
[self.view addSubview:curtain];
[curtain drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
```

But in this case, I haven't the result which I'm expecting, and drawRect isn't calling. I hope there is easy way to create custom Views for universal Apps.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in .h file 
    #import

```
@interface CurtainView : UIView

@end
```

put this code in .m file

```
#import "CurtainView.h"

@implementation CurtainView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
   // Drawing code
   NSLog(@"there should be some animation on view appirance");
}
```

now call this UIView form your viewcontroller class. this will call drawRect

```
CurtainView* curtain = [[CurtainView alloc] init];
NSLog(@"before");
[curtain drawRect:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:curtain];
```

you can call your viewcontroller class

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
     self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
 } else {
     self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
 }
```

Comment: I putted only the fragments of my code in the question. There is "#import". It's seems that problem is in loading "objectAtIndex:0" from the bungle - It load not this UIView which I expect =((. But< still, thanks.

Comment: and in your answer: there no mechanism for loadin *.xib for iPhone/iPad.

Comment: =) It should be UIView class, but not UIViewController. I want to create universal View, which I will be able to add in different viewControllers.

Comment: CurtainView is UIView Class that you add in view controller.

Comment: I'd advise against calling drawRect: directly. The docs specifically state that it shouldn't be done. Search for "You should never call this method directly yourself." in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 0):

ok. sorry, I got my misstake:

it's need to use :

```
[self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Curtain_iPhone" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

instead my:

```
self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurtainView_iphone" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope it will helpful for some one.

moreover, I don't know why, but property "opaque" for the View should be set in "init" method, not only in IB.